# Copy paste through selenium Python?

Tags: javascript, python, html, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Can I control + A and then somehow get the text that was highlighted with the control + A?
All in Selenium Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this should work

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

src_elem = find_element_by_name("source_element")
dist_elem = find_element_by_name("distance_element")
src_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a') # select all the text
src_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c') # copy it
dist_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v') # paste
```

In case that is not enough try clicking on the element before sending keys to it, like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

src_elem = find_element_by_name("source_element")
dist_elem = find_element_by_name("distance_element")
src_elem.click()
src_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a') # select all the text
src_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c') # copy it
dist_elem.click()
dist_elem.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v') # paste
```

Comment: instead of pasting it to another element, can I save it in a variable and for example print it in the terminal?

Comment: yes, but this is not exactly what you asked about :)

Comment: Sorry. Can you help me with the new question?

Comment: Yes, but this is definitely a new question. So please accept this my answer since I answered what you asked about, and I guess I answered correctly, and after that please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the copied text in the variable then you can use pyperclip

First You need to select and copy all text using Send_keys

```
send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'a')
send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'c')
```

Then with the help of pyperclicp you can save the copied text in variable

```
selected_text = pyperclip.paste()
print(selected_text)
```