# Copy text in python and paste by Ctrl + V in webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, copy-paste, sendkeys

I have one site where I can't enter a `password` using `send_keys` , I have to use Ctrl+V there. But I don't know how this can be done, because I have `Passwords`, where all passwords are stored and I need to take it from there

```
from Passwords import password

#how to copy?

inputpassword = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "Path")
inputpassword.???

#how to paste by Ctrl + V
```

Comment: what site makes this problem? maybe it needs to put value in different widget, or maybe it needs to send it using JavaScript

Comment: I needed to automatically enter a mnemonic, which consists of 12 words, if you enter using "Ctrl" + "v", then the words are distributed independently over 12 cells. If send_keys is used, then all 12 words are entered into one cell. Or you would have to write code for each cell separately, which would take a lot of time

Comment: I'm not interesting what you want to do but I would like to see this page. And usually code can be repeated using `for`-loop and it doesn't need so much time.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible to provide a link. This is a Metamask extension.

Comment: pity, it is interesting case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 steps here:

1. Read the text from some file into the clipboard.
2. Paste from the clipboard into the web element.
   There are several ways you can read a text from file into the clipboard, for example

```py
import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy('The text to be copied to the clipboard.')
```

More examples and explanations can be find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11063458/python-script-to-copy-text-to-clipboard) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/579687/how-do-i-copy-a-string-to-the-clipboard).
Then you can simply paste the clipboard content into a web element input with Selenium with regular  `CTRL + V` keys

```py
//now paste your content from clipboard
el = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
el.send_keys(Keys.CONTROL + 'v')
```

More examples and explanations can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28637931/paste-command-using-selenium) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68072476/copy-paste-through-selenium-python)

Comment: I'm happy I could help here :)

Comment: Now a new problem, "Ctrl" and "v" are pressed in turn and instead of the password on the line I get just "v"

Comment: Maybe it should be `+`, not `,` there, as I edited the answer now. You can also see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322883/how-to-press-ctrlv-in-selenium-webdriver and several more examples here

Comment: Now everything is working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I know you already accepted an answer but there's no reason to put anything into the clipboard if you are reading the password from a file.

```
password = ... #read password string from file
inputpassword = driver.find_element(...)
inputpassword.send_keys(password)
```

or just simply

```
password = ... #read password string from file
driver.find_element(...).send_keys(password)
```

Pasting in the text offers no advantages only more code which means more places where things might go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but "Ctrl" + "v" was important for me, because send_keys could't be used in my case

Comment: @Ambamamba Why can't `send_keys()` be used? You never mentioned this in your question.